How to Handle Chat Session Closure When Agent Refreshes Tab or Disconnects in Customer Service Workspace?
I am using the Customer Service Workspace and facing a critical issue:
If a support agent refreshes the tab or gets disconnected from the chat for any reason, the chat session closes automatically, and there’s no way to reinitiate it.
Users don’t receive any alerts that the agent got disconnected, leaving them in a frustrating state.
Automated messages configured in the Workstream are not being triggered in this scenario.
I’d like to implement a workaround to handle this situation properly. Specifically:
Ensure users are notified when the agent disconnects.
Automate the creation of a case when such disconnections occur, so we can follow up promptly.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or implemented a solution? Any guidance or best practices would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
